# How to add items to shopping basket JSP

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jsp

Can't seem to find any good guides on how to do this directly on Google/Youtube.
Basically I have a list of products (code):

```
<sql:query var="result">
select * from inventory;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Other field(Probs price)</th>
<th>Item Stock</th>
<th>Order Stock</th>
<th>Buy option </th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_code}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_author}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_description}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_price}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item__stock_count}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_order_count}"/></td>
<td><a href="shoppingbasket.jsp">Order Now!</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</div>
```

The layout looks like this:

Code    Author   Description Price  Item Stock Buy Stock Buy Option

It is connected to mySQL databse. So obviously under all these headers is information. Under the "Buy Option" Has Buy on every row.

What I want to do is when I click buy on one row. It will get the item Code for that specific row and will Post the item on the page shoppingbasket.jsp.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not .jsp specific, but perhaps this can enlighten you.
Usually templating with onclick events can be done like so:

```
<td onclick="addToCart(row.item_code)"></td>
```

I'm not familiar with your exact syntax, but the idea is to call a function and passing the current row's id.

You would then have a javascript function like so:

```
function addToCart(id) {
   //POST request using 'id'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Have a slightly edited version of the question here:        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751475/is-it-possible-to-use-url-parameters-with-mysql-jsp

Comment: While javascript is one way to build a hit to your backend. Another would simply be using a normal HTML link. `<a href="shoppingbasket.jsp?action=addToCart&item_code=item_to_add">add to cart</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use a button to make a POST request. Why, you ask?

1. works without JavaScript
2. You want to use POST for requests that change things

So put your whole product list in a `<form>`, and make your buttons (one per product) like this:

`<button name="btnAddToCart" value="<c:out value='${row.item_code}'/>">Add to Cart</button>`

You should probably be using a server-side Model-View-Controller framework (Like Spring MVC) too. You would have a controller RequestMapping like this to accept your button POST:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/your-product-list-page", params={"btnAddToCart"})
```

You'll need a session-scoped object for your shopping cart.

While we're at it, you should be escaping stuff with `<c:out value="${...}"/>` to minimize risks of XSS. And you probably want a responsive CSS framework so your site works on mobile.