# Is it possible to use URL parameters with mySQL/JSP?

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

My code: This code first creates a table. The table is then populated with data from mySQL database. My problem is at the last bit with the ahref.

When you click buy it will take the item code for that specific row the buy you click is in and sends it to the next pad jsporder.jsp.

```
<sql:query var="result">
select * from inventory;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Other field(Probs price)</th>
<th>Item Stock</th>
<th>Order Stock</th>
<th>Buy option </th>
</tr>

<c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_code}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_author}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_description}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_price}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item__stock_count}"/></td>
<td><c:out value = "${row.item_order_count}"/></td>
<td><a href="jsporder.jsp?item_code=${row.item_code}">Buy!</a></td>
<td><a
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</div>
```

On the next page I want to use something like the request.getParameter("item_code"); method but for mySQl.

Code for mySQL now: (This is on jsporder.jsp page)

```
<sql:query var="result">
  select item__stock_count from inventory 
    where item_code="AA01-002";
</sql:query>
```

Now the item code is set at static AA01-002 but I want it to be dependent on what buy button you click. So is there anything such as:

```
<sql: query var="result">
 select item__stock_count from inventory
 where item_code="request.getParameter("item_code")
 </sql:query>
```

So the item code can be a range of different characters depending on what button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

you can use the scriplet

```
<%
 String itemCode = request.getParamenter("item_code");
%>

<sql: query var="result">
 select item__stock_count from inventory
 where item_code="${itemCode}"
</sql:query>
```